# Не работает переключение камер в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру и там есть компьютер с камерами. Когда игрок к нему подходит то на кнопку C они включаются и потом их можно переключать на цифры. Написал код - не работает, не могу понять почему. подскажите как правильно это делается.

```
public Camera playerCamera;
public Camera cam1;
public Camera cam2;
public int currentCamera = 1;
public bool onActive = false;

private void Start()
{
    onActive = false;
    playerCamera.enabled = true;
    cam1.enabled = false;
    cam2.enabled = false;

}

 void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
    {
        onActive = !onActive;
    }
}

 void Uptade()
{
    if (onActive == false)
    {
        playerCamera.enabled = true;
        cam1.enabled = false;
        cam2.enabled = false;
    }
    if (onActive)
    {
        playerCamera.enabled = false;

        switch (currentCamera)
        {
            case 1:
                cam1.enabled = true;
                cam2.enabled = false;

                break;
            case 2:
                cam1.enabled = false;
                cam2.enabled = true;
                break;

        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        {
            currentCamera = 1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
        {
            currentCamera = 2;
        }

    }
}
```